# Help identifying movie from Russia or similar

Tags: story-identification, movie

My recollection is very sketchy but this is what I remember....

- Film was possibly black and white
- I saw it as a child in the late '80s early '90s but it's older
- It was subtitled and in Russian or similar language
- It involved some astronauts  travelling in space with possibly time travel
- The astronauts (mostly men) encounter a planet/civilization of only women
- The women no longer need men to breed and are so become superior and possibly want to eliminate all men

That's all I have to go on, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another possibility is the 1984 Polish film, *[Sexmission](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/SexMission)* (*Seksmisja* in Polish). It involves a female-dominated society who reproduces via parthenogenesis and there is time travel of the forward variety. Moreover, it was originally in Polish (which is a Slavic tongue much like Russian) and it did have a release in Russia (as *Новые амазонки*). However, there is no space travel involved.

[image: Movie poster]

> The two protagonists, Max and Albert, played by Jerzy Stuhr and Olgierd Łukaszewicz, respectively, submit themselves in 1991 to the first human hibernation experiment. Instead of being awakened a few years later as planned, they wake up in the year 2044, in a post-nuclear world. By then, humans have retreated to underground living facilities, and, as a result of subjection to a specific kind of radiation, all males have died out. Women reproduce through parthenogenesis, living in an oppressive feminist society, where the apparatchiks teach that women suffered under males until males were removed from the world.

Comment: Excellent find. This is the one. Thank you.

Comment: And here I thought that one was a stab in the dark... :)

Comment: Actually there are no time travel, just our time and then plot moves to the future.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that is not much to go on. *[Cat-Women of the Moon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/CatWomenOfTheMoon)* is about a pair of astronauts encountering a society of only women and it was indeed black-and-white, and most of them are none too happy about men. However, it's the moon, no time travel, and it was originally in English although I'm sure someone has translated it into Russian at some point.

[image: Movie poster]

> An expedition to the Moon encounters a race of "Cat-Women", the last eight survivors of a 2-million-year-old civilization, deep within a cave where they have managed to maintain the remnants of a breathable atmosphere that once covered the Moon. The remaining air will soon be gone, and they must leave if they are to survive. They plan to steal the expedition's spaceship and migrate to Earth.

There were a number of films very similar to this one released at this time, including one explicit remake, *[Missile to the Moon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/MissileToTheMoon)*.