# Please name this 70's/80's (foreign) dystopian totalitarian sci-fi movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw this in the late eighties.
Boy escapes the grasp of an all female command and having been misled to believe a holocaust type scenario joins with a girl.

They work their way through a series of rooms. The final scene, I remember, involves the boy slicing the wall with a knife to reveal sunlight and sand (beach or desert).

It was a false lie in a totalitarian underground cult. I believe it was subtitled thus foreign.

Comment: It's not [Sexmission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhwqRnZli8U) is it? Warning, this film contains much nudity and appalling acting.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy!  What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: It sounds a little like the film "The City of Embers" which was based on a book by the same name. According to Wiki: " Similar to Suzanne Martel's The City Under Ground published in 1963 and Helen Mary Hoover's This Time of Darkness published in 1980" . May provide a clue?

Comment: @Valorum its not "appalling" but sadly lots of the jokes would be lost on people not living in the Eastern Block

Comment: It was seksmisja or sexmission. I thought the two men were one boy and i remember the film being darker and more sinister than it is. It is on youtube thankfully for me to verify that this is the very film. A scene that i now remember is the scene of the swimming women through the wall. Many thanks to  Valorum and Yasskier.

Comment: @Valorum Nudity doesn't bother me, I have seen both men and women with nothing on before, and the bad acting... Well, it still had some entertainment value when I was 15. Let's see if it still does, now that I'm 46. :D

Answer (score 5):

### Sexmission (1984, Poland)

[image]

Two male volunteers are placed in hibernation, but the planned 2 years is extended to over 40, when World War 3 erupts. Mass usage of biological weapons wipes male population; surviving women live underground under the rule of "League of Women" - a pastiche of Party (with capital "P") that keeps demonizing the (now extinct) men as monster.

When Maks and Albert are recovered, the League decides to turn them into women. Trying to avoid this fate, with help from one of researchers they decide to go to the surface, knowing that that the radiation would kill them in less than two weeks. But exploring the wasteland they quickly find a "forcefield" that Maks attacks with a knife and tears through easily: They find themselves in a beautiful land - the wasteland is just a painting surrounding the periscope, providing false sense of danger to the inhabitants of the underground complex.

Comment: If so, that's a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135104/help-identifying-movie-from-russia-or-similar/135110#135110

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The OP has verified that this answer is correct in [a comment on the question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140267/please-name-this-70s-80s-foreign-dystopian-totalitarian-sci-fi-movie/140273#comment357434_140267), so I'm closing this one as duplicate.