# Polish film about two men who end up in a future where the need for men has been eliminated

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this in the mid 80's with subtitles. It seemed to me that it wasn't very recent even then, so it could possibly have been made in the 70's or the 60's.

Two men end up in a future after a war which devastated the earth, and forced humans to live underground. I don't remember how they ended up in the future; time travel, having been frozen or having been away, for example in space, for a long time are reasons I can think of. However, they key plot is that the need for men has been eliminated, and the women reproduce by some process involving in vitro tanks. Their society is lead by an elderly woman referred to only as Her Excellency. As the story goes on, the two men find that the surface is actually habitable, and that Her Excellency has kept that fact from her subjects, and when they confront her, she shows her true self, and it turns out that she's actually a man, and that he hates having to pose as a woman. The three of them devise a plan to re-introduce men, and eventually they release their own semen in the in vitro tanks. The final scene shows a young woman picking a baby up from one of the tanks only to discover that it's boy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the 1984 film [*Sexmission*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexmission) (*Seksmisja* in Polish). From Wikipedia's plot description (emphasis mine):

> The two protagonists, Max and Albert, played by Jerzy Stuhr and Olgierd Łukaszewicz, respectively, submit themselves in 1991 to the first human hibernation experiment. Instead of being awakened a few years later as planned, they wake up in the year 2044, in a post-nuclear world. By then, humans have retreated to underground living facilities, and, as a result of subjection to a specific kind of radiation, **all males have died out. Women reproduce through parthenogenesis, living in an oppressive feminist society**, where the apparatchiks teach that women suffered under males until males were removed from the world.
>
> The cold-shoulder treatment Max and Albert receive from the women, their character differences and specific realities of future life serve as background of many humorous encounters. The plot thickens when it turns out that the females have no interest in the rebirth of men, and that for the good of society, the two males are to be killed or "naturalised", i.e. undergo a sex-change. While trying to break away, Max and Albert find out the impact of their masculinity on women. With one of the scientists on their side, the men choose freedom and prefer to escape and die outside. In doing so, they discover the truth: radiation was just a feminist lie to keep women underground and the surviving male population were "naturalised" into women by the feminists when they took power in the post-war period. As a result of discovering the truth, both Max and Albert begin thinking of bringing the world back to normal.

This film has also been provided as the answer to [another ID question on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135104/31394).

[image: poster]
[image: poster]

Comment: If so, it's a duplicate if http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135104/help-identifying-movie-from-russia-or-similar/135110#135110 (accepted) and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140267/please-name-this-70s-80s-foreign-dystopian-totalitarian-sci-fi-movie/140273#140273 (not accepted), both of which have movie posters if you want to lift them. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks! Link and posters added.

Comment: That is undoubtedly the one. I googled the title after reading your answer, and I found a few images I recognised.